# How to programmatically add a line of space in between paragraphs in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I tried using /n after each paragraph like so:

```
"THE COZY, INVITING FEEL OF A CENTURIES-OLD EUROPEAN GATHERING SPOT INSPIRES THE PLACE.\n Creating a space from hand with dark wood interiors and eclectic old world accents, the husband and wife duo behind the Grail (as our loyalists, call us) brought a little bit of their ancestral heritage to design an authentic tavern amongst West Plano’s suburban landscape.\n
```

but this is what it looks like:

[image: current]

I am trying to make it look like this:

[image]

Comment: the text you posted doesn't match the screenshot one.

Comment: It was a lot of text, I only put the first 2 paragraphs

Comment: It's more the way I was doing it, not the text itself that's the main issue

Comment: tried adding multiple \n ?

Comment: That worked! -So simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using one more \n (i.e. \n\n) will have the effect you want:

```
textView.text = "THE COZY, INVITING FEEL OF A CENTURIES-OLD EUROPEAN GATHERING SPOT INSPIRES THE PLACE.\n\n Creating a space from hand with dark wood interiors and eclectic old world accents, the husband and wife duo behind the Grail (as our loyalists, call us) brought a little bit of their ancestral heritage to design an authentic tavern amongst West Plano’s suburban landscape.\n"
```